# The first number have been repating every time ı couldnt understand why this happen

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int x;

    scanf("%d",&x);
    while(x<=10)
    {
        printf("%d\n",x);
        x+=1;
    }
}
```

why this code gives us that(for ex. we run the program and write 1 and push the enter the output like this

```
1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

can you tell me why this is happining) but  if I add `x+=1;` after the `scanf` it does what I want w/o repeating the first number ,thank you.

Comment: Are you counting the `1` that you typed as the first `1`?

Comment: The first 1 is just the computer echoing what you type. The program doesn't repeat any output.

Comment: what is mean by that echoing ı did not order printf as you see,2>yes ı count

Comment: Type `1` but don't press enter. What do you see? You should see `1` in the terminal right? That's the echo. Now press enter and you should see the 1-10 output as expected. So that first `1` is just what you typed. If that is not it then please show your **exact** run log. What you have shown is not the exact log as your code prints a newline and not commas.

Comment: ı see now, thank you for answers have a nice works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is standard behavior for not just the output to be written to the screen, but also the input. So, if you enter the number 1 and press enter, it will echo the number 1 onto the screen.

In order to make it clear what the input is and what the output is, I suggest you change your program to the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int x;

    printf( "The following is echoed input:\n" );

    scanf("%d",&x);

    printf( "The following is the actual output:\n" );

    while(x<=10)
    {
        printf("%d\n",x);
        x+=1;
    }
}
```